# Log and view all IP's that download or access anything from my Server Apache Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am trying to find a specific answer on how to log all accesses and requests to my http apache server on ubuntu 16.04.

I want to know what IP address accesses say `www.1.1.1.1/index.php` or `logo.png` and at what time from the server side log ***not a php script*** or something.

Comment: Don't the access.log and error.log in /var/log/apache2/ already log that information?

Comment: Ok, I checked it again and yes it decided to work. The only issue I'm having is that the list seems to delete parts of itself, I would like it to be continual.